# how to convert string into html and loop through it in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am using the following code

```
 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                string site = "http://www.nokia.com
                webBrowserControl.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute));
                webBrowserControl.LoadCompleted += webBrowserControl_LoadCompleted;
            });
private void webBrowserControl_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = webBrowserControl.SaveToString();
}
```

How do I loop through this result string to find out elements like  s and all

```
<div class="result-wrapper">
```

Tried to convert this string to XMLDocument but getting the error.

Please help me... thanks

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'lang' is a duplicate attribute name. Line 23, position 33

Answer (score 1):

You should not use XML document parser to pase html, because html schema is different than Html. you can use Agility Pack to parse html below is link on how you can use agility Pak

[HTML Agility Pack - Windows Phone 8](http://www.tareqateik.com/html-agility-pack%E2%80%93windows-phone-8#.U8bBMfmSyBo)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Muhammad Saifullah

Answer (score 0):

It will throw you an exception when it is not a perfect XML document. It should have proper opening and closing tag. Check your html document with some online XML Validator and then proceed with that.

If you are going to parse only few tags, then identify the substring from your html document using "string.IndexOf()" and use that substring to load your XML Document.

Else, you have to do it manually or by using HTML Agility pack. But Html Agility pack needs some libraries from Silverlight 4.0 which is not recommended by microcoft.

So, doing manually is my choice.